# VS2019 temp files

Tags: visual-studio, temp

I made a pretty hard decision of whether to get VS2019 because it takes a lot of space. I finally got it and I have a lot of temp files from the VS installation that start with dd. If I delete those, will I be able to use VS2019?

Comment: what temp files ? from the VS installation ?

Comment: @Max Yes. From the VS installation

Comment: Are they in the %temp% folder? If so, yes, you can delete them...assuming VS isn't running. It likes to use the temp folder for things like previewing a code file from the solution explorer prior to actually opening it.

Comment: @Casey Thank you! VS runs faster now